# Speed up dataframe loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm running two different but very similar loops over a pandas dataframe and am wondering whether there is some sort of groupby operation that would allow me to speed this up by avoiding a loop.

```
for x in df.var1:
    df[df.var1==x, 'var2'] = np.max(df[df.var1==x, 'var2'])
```

That is, given that there are multiple rows with the same value of `var1`, I want to set the value of `var2` for all of these rows to the maximum that `var2` obtains over all these rows.

I feel like I should be able to do this without a for loop, but for some reason I can't figure out how. Ideas?

Comment: Please add a sample of the whole dataframe and an expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace a column with the max value in that column, grouped by the values in another column.  You should be able to use `groupby()` and `transform(max)` to get what you want:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"var1": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'var2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
>>> df
   var1  var2
0     1     1
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     2     4
4     3     5
5     3     6
>>> df['var2'] = df.groupby('var1').transform(max)
>>> df
   var1  var2
0     1     2
1     1     2
2     2     4
3     2     4
4     3     6
5     3     6
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I was looking for. Might be worthwhile to add that in a dataframe with lots of columns, one should just transform the particular column one is interested in, e.g. `df.groupby('var1').var2.transform(max)` (when I leave this out, the groupby/transform operation actually takes longer than the for loop on my dataframe).